# Proving the two matrices generate the group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of $2\times 2$ integer matrices with determinant 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, determinant

Can someone please help me apply elementary row and column operations to prove that two matrices $g = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $h = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ generate the group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of $2\times 2$ integer matrices with determinant 1. My work is below. Thank you for your time and help.

$\textit{My Solution.}$ Now, $|g| = \det g = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$ (by Row 1 minus Row 2) $= 1-0 = 1,$ and $|h| = \det h = \begin{vmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{vmatrix} = - \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1  \end{vmatrix}$ (interchanging Row 1 and Row 2) $$ = \begin{vmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix},$$ by taking out $(-1)$ from Row 2. Then we have $1- 0 = 1.$ Hence, $g$ and $h$ generate the group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of $2\times 2$ integer matrices with determinant 1.

Comment: You don't show that they generate, just that they lie in.

Comment: I see, thank you @ahulpke

Comment: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf << It may be complete proof of your Q.

Comment: hi brucemcmc; are you familiar with what it means for a set of elements to generate a group?